# SSH: forward port on intermediate machine to local network

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I have a master that is reachable from the outside on a static IP (1.2.3.4). From the master, I can connect to a slave that resides in a local network (10.0.0.1). Currently, my `.ssh/config` looks like this:

```
Host master
  Hostname 1.2.3.4
  User pi
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host slave
  Hostname 10.0.0.1
  User pi
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ProxyJump master
```

With the above, I can comfortably connect to the slave using `ssh slave`. Unfortunately, this does not work with Filezilla, which only lets me specify a host name and a port. That's why I want to redirect port 2201 on the master to the slave SSH. In other words, I want `ssh pi@1.2.3.4 -p 2201` to be equivalent to running `ssh slave`. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Edit:

Adding the `-t nat` flag I executed the commands suggested by @timmeyh. `iptables -t nat -L --line-numbers` now gives

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:2201 to:10.0.0.1:22

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    SNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             10.0.0.1             tcp dpt:ssh to:10.0.0.0
```

where 10.0.0.0 is the master address. But `ssh pi@1.2.3.4 -p 2201` refuses the connection. I also made sure that `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` is enabled.

Comment: How can 10.0.0.0 be the master address? This is the network id and cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with iptables:

`iptables -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2201 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:22

iptables -A POSTROUTING -d 10.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j SNAT --to-source <10.x.x.x IP of master>`

The first command will tell the server to forward the traffic comming in on port 2201 towards port 22 of ip 10.0.0.1

The second one will tell that all traffic going towards port 22 of 10.0.0.1 must have the correct source ip (in this case the 10.x.x.x address of your 1.2.3.4 server) so that the destination (10.0.0.1) knows where to route it back to.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I edited the question to respond.